# How to convert from a constructor to a string in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, constructor, type-conversion, show

I am trying to output a hand of cards in string format, but I can't drop the word "Numeric" from the rank of the card, I would prefer to do this without a helper function because it seems really messy, any recommendations to do this without a helper function. Also, when I'm using the `display` function, I'm using `putStr (display x)` in the Prelude. Here's the code so far for it:

```
displayCard :: Card -> String
displayCard c = show (rank c) ++ " of " ++ show (suit c) ++ "\n"

display :: Hand -> String
display Empty = "\n"
display (Add c h) = displayCard c
                    ++ display h

displayRank :: Rank -> String
displayRank (Numeric 2) = "2"
displayRank (Numeric 3) = "3"
displayRank (Numeric 4) = "4"
displayRank (Numeric 5) = "5"
displayRank (Numeric 6) = "6"
displayRank (Numeric 7) = "7"
displayRank (Numeric 8) = "8"
displayRank (Numeric 9) = "9"
displayRank (Numeric 10) = "10"
displayRank Jack = "Jack"
displayRank Queen = "Queen"
displayRank King = "King"
displayRank Ace = "Ace"
```

Comment: Is `rank` supposed to be the same as `displayRank`?

Comment: @mkriger1: I guess `rank` is a "getter" of the `Card` type, but since we do not see the data definitions, we can not know for sure.

Comment: `displayRank (Numeric a) = show a`. But it is recommended to write a `Show` instance for your type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would prefer to do this without a helper function because it seems really messy

Assuming you have something like the following types,

```hs
data Card = Card { cardRank :: Rank, cardSuit :: Suit }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Rank = Numeric Int | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Suit = Diamonds | Clubs | Hearts | Spades
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

then it would make sense to write helper functions

```hs
displayRank :: Rank -> String
displayRank (Numeric n) = show n
displayRank otherRank = show otherRank

displaySuit :: Suit -> String
displaySuit = show

displayCard :: Card -> String
displayCard (Card rank suit) = ...
```

but you could also combine them:

```hs
displayCard :: Card -> String
displayCard (Card (Numeric n) suit) = ...
displayCard (Card otherRank suit) = ...
```

Having properly designed helper functions is not messy. On the contrary.

Answer (score 3):

What you accomplish with `show (rank c)`,

```
rank ::        Card -> Rank
show ::                Rank -> String
```

you can accomplish with `displayRank (rank c)`

```
rank ::        Card -> Rank
displayRank ::         Rank -> String
```

(speaking of types).